# How do I update a column for all rows in a table with different values based on the function i wrote?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am having a table where I want to update the column `tempID` (null for now) for all the rows.

The table is already having multiple records.

I want to update for each and every rows (randomly) with string I generate from my function?

```
tempID    Name       Address
null      xyz        asdf
null      abc        asdfds
```

I want to update the table so that it will be below:

```
tempID    Name       Address
emp101    xyz        asdf
emp102    abc        asdfds
```

This is like assigning an id to the employee after entry of data which was done on excel and export into this table.

Comment: please give us some input data and expected output.

Comment: You are using VB.NET, dumb way to do that is using loop.  Try it by yourself first, or enhance your question by providing [mcve]

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly check

Comment: Your example results do not look very random.

Comment: It doesnt matter if its random or in sequence but i require that id to be assigned and updated to the employees. I tried with looping and the id is generated but on update query its not updating accordingly. I was wondering what should i put in where clause.     Dim upsql = "Update tb_Tempmember set tempID = '" & id & "'

Answer (score 0):

You can try below snippet. I have tried to use ORA_HASH value to generate  random unique identifier. Hope this helps.

```
alter session set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = CHAR;



CREATE TABLE emp_tab
  (
    empid   VARCHAR2(100),
    name    VARCHAR2(100),
    Address VARCHAR2(1000)
  );

INSERT INTO emp_tab
SELECT NULL,'Avrajit'||level,'PUNE'||level FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 10;

CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION gen_random_empid(
      emp_name IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
    emp_id VARCHAR2(100);
  begin
    SELECT 'Emp'||ora_hash(emp_name) INTO emp_id FROM dual;
    return emp_id;
  end;

UPDATE emp_tab SET empid = gen_random_empid(NAME);

SELECT * FROM emp_tab;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but its not the answer im looking for. Actually in my vb.net code, i want to update the id from my own generated function, and then for each row of the table i want to update the tempID as below.        Dim upsql = "Update tb_Tempmember set tempID = '" & GetNextid() & "'

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. What i did was i assigned a normal sequence number 1,2,3... to tempID when exporting from excel sheet, and then i update the query like this

Dim upsql = "Update tb_Tempmember set tempID = '" & generatenextid() & "' where tempid = '" & CStr(mysequenceid) & "'"

This is in the loop.

Thanks for your support.